# How to pass a object of a class to a function within the object's class function?

Tags: c++

I need to pass the object of the class that i'm working on to a function. For me it's hard to explain, so I made a simple example.

I tried using 'this' operator, hoping that it will send 'this' object to the function, but it didn't work. I also tried googling the problem, but I could't find any sensible answers.

```
#include <iostream>
unsing namespace std;
class apple;

int eatApple(apple & a)
{
   a.var1=0;
   a.var2=0;

   return 0;
}

class apple
{
   int var1;
   int var2;

   void cutApple();
};

void apple::cutApple()
{
   var1/=2;
   var2/=2;

   eatApple(/*HERE I HAVE TO PASS THE OBJECT OF THE CLASS TO THE FUNCTION*/);

}

int main()
{
   apple Apple;

   Apple.cutApple();

   return 0;
}
```

Note that this code is just a example of the problem. Where i have written in the /* */, that's where i tried the 'this' operator, but i didn't work.

Comment: Do you know that `this` is a pointer? Do you know how to reference the object a pointer points to, instead of the pointer itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function header looks like this: `int eatApple(apple & a)`, which means it accepts a reference to `apple`. `this` is always a pointer (not a reference), therefore you need to dereference it:

```
eatApple(*this);
```

Comment: yep, now i works great! Thanks for the help and good explanation:D